# Mark specflow skipped test status as passed

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation, specflow

Im using some Example in each scenario where diiferent link as describe
I'm trying for some link(according to some conditions) to mark the test as skipped in the beforeScenario hooks.
I was able to do it. but now i want for the skipped test to be marked as Passed and not as skipped

Tried several assertion but none working to provide a passed status as well as terminate the current running scenario for that link.

Comment: We do not have enough information to provide an answer. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Comment: I also think you are asking about the solution, and not the problem. Is the problem that some scenarios are not relevant or some steps are optional based on configuration?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes you are right according to some configurations in our specflowAppsetting some scenarios might not need to be run. Adding if conditions in our step implementation might be an overhead that why i was wondering how can we achieve same from hooks itself. I tried assert.Inconclusive before and its working great. its marking it as skipped and ending the scenario rightaway but the issue that on our custom runner( Where our test runs) it supports only passing or failure and no skip.

Comment: @GregBurghardt Its marking the skip as error. Thats why im trying to find a way to end the scenario based on some configuration(conditons) on the hooks itself , terminate the test and marking it as pass

Comment: Does `Assert.Pass("Your message here.")` not work for your needs?

Comment: @GregBurghardt when used in hooks it does not. It does continue to execute the steps

Comment: I keep coming back to this question, but I don't have enough information to provide an answer. Can you [edit] your question with some [repro] indicating where you want to mark these skipped tests as passing?